# How did it achieve multiple inheritance before java 8 when there are same method signatures in interfaces

Tags: java, oop

We know that if we want to achieve multiple inheritance in java we can use interfaces. If a class implements two interfaces which have the same method signature how did it achieve multiple inheritance before java 8?

Comment: Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. Even though default methods in interfaces brings us one step closer, it's still not entirely the same. No, we can't achieve multiple inheritance as it is in other languages with interfaces. After Java 8 (unfortunately) we're getting close, but before Java 8, there was no such thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd just implement the method, that's all. If both methods had compatible contracts (and your implementation satisfied them), then it worked out fine. If not, then your class was buggy with respect to at least one of its interfaces.

That's unchanged in Java 8. It's true even if one of the interfaces provides a default implementation -- that just means your class doesn't need to write it. But that implementation still applies to all methods with the same signature, regardless of which interface they're for.

Answer (score 0):

We already know **Java doesn't support Multiple Inheritance.**

But **It can be achieved using multiple Interfaces & Object Composition** regardless of Java Version.
This can be implemented with older version of Java as well in classical way.

In this blog It is explained very well with an easy example.

https://javaterian.blogspot.com/2015/01/multiple-inheritance-in-java.html

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227) https://stackoverflow.com/a/69713710/7733418

Answer (score 0):

It was a language design decision to not support multiple inheritancem (after C++): Class extends Class, but additionally introduce *interfaces*: Class implement Interface1, ..., InterfaceN.

The reason was the resolution of conflicting implementations in multiple parents: it simply is not logical to pick one, or even consider the conflicting method having the same meaning, semantics.

A child of `List` and `Set` would have `List.add` and `Set.add`, but would need its own `add` to call both. This easily leads to oversight errors und unclear APIs, and also multiple inheritance has no unavoidable and heavy use.

To your question:

```
class Foo<T> implements Set<T>, List<T> {
    ...
}
```

Here `add` is an API requirement. Most likely there is some form of delegation:

- a field `List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();`
- a field `Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();`

And implementing `add(T)` then is meaningfull, without inheritance obfuscating things: list.add+set.add.